# LATEX Removing part of shaded area in polar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, texworks, polarplot

I've been working on creating the following picture using TikZ.

[image]

The following code is as far as I've gotten.

```
\documentclass[width=5cm, height=5cm, border=2mm]{standalone}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

% cartesian coordinates
\draw[-] (-2cm,0cm) -- (2cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,3.1cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

% sine graph with shading
\draw [thick, domain=0:2*pi, samples=200, smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= 
{1+1*sin(\x r)});
\filldraw [thick, even odd rule, fill=gray!50, fill opacity=0.3, domain=pi/6:5*pi/6, 
samples=200, smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {1+1*sin(\x r)}) 
(0,1.5)circle(1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

I was attempting with this code to first plot the sine graph(the one with a little dimple at the bottom) and then plot the shaded circle graph. The sine graph will only exist between pi/6 and 5pi/6, thus it'll "even odd rule" with the existing shaded circle and remove the shading within that region but as seen below it doesn't quite work out the way I was expecting. Pardon my limp explanation of the *even odd rule*, it's new to me and I'm still learning how to competently use it.

The above code produces the following polar plot.

[image]

How can I remove the obvious gray semicircle so it'll be like the sketch above?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution does not use the `even odd rule` option, just exploits the fact that you know the intersection points

```
\documentclass[width=5cm, height=5cm, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

% cartesian coordinates
\draw[-] (-2cm,0cm) -- (2cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
\draw[-] (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,3.1cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

% sine graph with shading
\fill [thick, fill=gray!50, fill opacity=0.3, domain=pi/6:5*pi/6,
samples=200, smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {1+1*sin(\x r)})
arc (210 : -30 : 1.5);
\draw [thick, domain=0:2*pi, samples=200, smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius=
{1+1*sin(\x r)}) (0, 1.5) circle (1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In hind sight a few hours after I posted this question I was thinking and realized that the _even odd rule_ doesn't apply in this instance, like you had pointed out. It's a shame I didn't catch it earlier, but regardless thank you for your patience and response. It really does help me learn this language. Cheers

Comment: @salami_pirate if you saw the issue that means you are on the right track :)